# Files became read-only in my Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux, readonly

```
rm [EgyBest].Vikings.S04E20.BluRay.1080p.x264.mp4
rm: cannot remove '[EgyBest].Vikings.S04E20.BluRay.1080p.x264.mp4': Read-only file system
```

Why did my simple videos or C files became read-only files?

Comment: It's not your files that are read-only, it's the filesystem. A filesystem can become read-only in case of errors. So,  are these files on a specific filesystem? Describe

Comment: Please tell the absolute path of the file and show the output of `mount`.  Please [edit] your question to add this information. Is there anything special you did or noticed before this happened? (e.g. installation of software, power loss, noise from the hard disk) The problem might not be related to the fact that you use Kali Linux, but is there a specific reason for this choice of distribution?

Comment: @bodo The only common reason for people to choose Kali as a desktop distribution would violate the code of conduct if I were to describe it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the error message:

`read-only filesystem`.

The filesystem that that particular file is on is currently mounted read-only. If you didn't do that intentionally, the most common cause is that the system encountered hardware errors while trying to read or write to the disk and remounted the filesystem read-only to prevent further errors from causing irreparable damage.

Check your kernel logs with either `dmesg` or `journalctl -k` depending on your system  and look for the phrase 'mounting read-only', then scroll slightly up to see *why* it felt that was necessary.

It *could* be a one-time error in which case a reboot should fix your problem, but if it isn't, rebooting without checking what's actually wrong is a good way to cause aforementioned irreparable damage.

... Also in a mostly unrelated note, Kali Linux is *not* meant for desktop use and even its own developers recommend you don't use it as anything other than the pentesting tool it's intended to be. Please consider listening to them and installing a *real* distribution to your desktop for general use.